# How to set crystal report's database location programmatically?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

So I've got two PCs, both having a database named TKIC_Data_Storage.accdb in both of its AppData folder. I created crystalreport1.rpt in PC1 but the problem is that when i run it in PC2 the database will not be detected. How can I set a dynamic database location for the crystalreport.rpt during runtime?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend making use of [this SAP connection string utility](http://www.sdn.sap.com/notes?id=0001553921&boj=/sap/bc/bsp/spn/scn_bosap/notes.do?access=69765F6D6F64653D3939382669765F7361706E6F7465735F6E756D6265723D30303031353533393231) or checking [this sample code from SAP](http://search.sap.com/ui/notes?id=0001535347&boj=/sap/bc/bsp/spn/scn_bosap/notes.do?access=69765F6D6F64653D3939382669765F7361706E6F7465735F6E756D6265723D30303031353335333437&ssocompatible) for changing the database connection at runtime. The actual code you need depends on the database type you connect to.

Various samples can also be found at StackOverflow: [How do I change a Crystal Report's ODBC database connection at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674363/how-do-i-change-a-crystal-reports-odbc-database-connection-at-runtime)